# Vertical Line through z=0 in complex plane mapped with f(z)=(1+z)/(1-z)

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry, mobius-transformation

I have the vague notion that the imaginary axis maps to a circle with f(z)=(1+z)/(1-z).
$$
\begin{array}{lll}
f(\infty) & = & -1\\
f(i) & = & e^{\pi/4}\\
f(-i) & = & e^{-\pi/4}\\
f(0) & = & 1\\
\end{array}
$$
Seems to be mapping only in the right side of a unitary circle.  Is this correct?

Comment: Please use [LaTeX typesetting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in your questions.

Comment: $f(i)=e^{\pi/4}$ is not correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It maps the imaginary axis onto the unit circle minus $-1$. Note that, if $t\in\mathbb R$,$$\frac{1+it}{1-it}=\frac{(1+it)^2}{(1+it)(1-it)}=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}+\frac{2t}{1+t^2}i$$and the complex numbers of this form are precisely the elements of the unit circle (with one exception: $-1$).